# Kubernetes ingress routes with url parameter

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

As I will have no wifi tomorrow this is more some kind of theory crafting. I need to prepare the ingress files in "offline mode".

I want to route from `ApplicationA` to `ApplicationB`. These routes are hopefully able to carry url parameter. Both applications are using `spring boot` and `REST`. The cluster is (currently) set up by `minikube`.

So e.g. I got this url in `ServiceA`: `http://url.com/customerapi/getCustomerById?id=5`. This url should hit a method which is defined in `ApplicationB`. `ApplicationB` is reachable using `customerservice` and port 31001.

Is it as simple as the ingress below? Thats pretty much straight forward. Best regards.

I would define an `kubernetes ingress` like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: serviceA
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /customerapi
        backend:
          serviceName: customerservice
          servicePort: 31001
```

Comment: This parameter is only in URL, or you can pass that in header?

Comment: Only in the url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to route traffic coming from web into two backends based on the url.

You can set your Ingress the following way:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: url.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test1
        backend:
          serviceName: test1-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /test2
        backend:
          serviceName: test2-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

This will route all from `url.com/test1` to backend `test1-svc` and all from `url.com/test2` to backend `test2-svc`.

If you need to use the parameter inside the `Url`, I think the following will work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/query-routing: default/query-routing
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: url.com

---

kind:ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: query-routing
data:
  mapping: |-
    [{
      "field": "getCustomerById",
      "value": "1",
      "path": "customerapi/",
      "service": "customerservice",
      "port": "31001"
    }]
```

But please test it on your example, as there are not enough details in your question.

There is  a way of catching the parameter from `Header`  using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` Annotations. This particular one is being used by Shopify and usage is explained [here](https://github.com/Shopify/ingress/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#server-snippet). For more annotations please check Kubernetes [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/).

Comment: I don't think the "ingress.kubernetes.io/query-routing" annotation is part of the API
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4728