# How to use Ingress Nginx to route requests by url query string?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

We would like to use annotation for redirecting requests to a different backend service based on url args (query)

Example:

https://example.com/foo?differentQueryString=0 -> service-a

https://example.com/foo/bar?queryString=0 - service-b

- Notes: path does not matter, this can be either /foo/bar or /foo or /bar/foo

We followed up on this

[Kubernetes NGINX Ingress controller - different route if query string exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994472/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-different-route-if-query-string-exists)

and this

[Kubernetes ingress routes with url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858277/kubernetes-ingress-routes-with-url-parameter)

But we don't want to setup ConfigMap just for this and also we don't want to duplicate requests to the ingress but rewriting

This is what we tried

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
 annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($args ~ queryString=0){
            backend.service.name = service-b
          }
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-a
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-b
                port:
                  number: 80
```

We were expecting to get the response but we got 502 from the Ingress Nginx

Answer (score 1):

We managed to find a nice solution without rewriting and ConfigMap

Works great and also include Nginx Ingress metrics so we can do HPA accordingly

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
 annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($args ~ queryString=0){
            set $proxy_upstream_name "default-service-b-80";
            set $proxy_host $proxy_upstream_name;
            set $service_name "service-b"; 
          }
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-a
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-b
                port:
                  number: 80
```

$proxy_upsteam_name convention is NAMESPACE-SERVICE_NAME-PORT